# Merging 2 Isochrone Maps

Tags: qgis, heat-map, time, driving

Through the [OpenRouteService](https://openrouteservice.org/directions?n1=55.383929&n2=-1.79028&n3=10&b=0&k1=en-US&k2=km), I've generated 2 driving time maps from 2 points approximately 60km from each other. Screenshots below - each colour represents 10 minutes.

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to find the 'half way point' between Alnwick and Duns. Would anyone have an idea how to make this a cumulative travel time map?

Comment: Wouldn't it be as simple as finding the union of the polygons for matching time classes? So the union of the 10 minute polygons (yields empty set); 20 minute (empty set); 30 minutes (non-empty set)...

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think I was just overthinking it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do using OpenRouteService however TravelTime platform can find this intersection for you on their app using the 'filter intersection' slider. I've added an example of where's reachable within a 45 minute drive from Duns & Alnwick. Full disclosure I work for the company that creates this software. Edit travel time areas here: 
http://try.traveltimeplatform.com/maps-sign-up/

[image: Duns & Alnwick travel time map]